# update url.action dynamically with razor variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{
    Layout = null;             
    string something = "";            
}

<head>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function VName(vwname) {
            if (vwname == "Dialog") {
                @ViewBag.viewname="Dialog"; 
            }
            else {
                @ViewBag.viewname="Fields";
            }

            @{something = ViewBag.viewname;}

            return @something;
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#modal-two" class="btn" onclick="@something= VName('')" >Modal!3</a>             
    <div class="modal" id="modal-two" aria-hidden="true"  >
        <div id="md1" class=" modal-dialog "   style=" width:650px; height :500px;  "> <input type="button" id="PostID" /> @something
            <iframe src='@Url.Action(something, "Treeview")'  frameBorder="0" style=" height:100%; width:100% ;"   ></iframe>
            <a id="nice"  href="#modal-one" class="btn" style=" visibility:hidden">Nice!</a>   
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to dynamically update the `Url.Action` in the iframe src but the razor variable `@someting` is getting updated in javascript but not reflecting in `Url.Action`. The same thing is happening with `ViewData`

Is there any other way to do this or something else to try the same.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is server side code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `function VName(vwname)` is javascript code which does not even exist at that point. And your javascript function cannot set the value of a `ViewBag` property (which is server side code)

Comment: but thats advantage in mvc   value can be updated in variable dynamically i am just trying to figure it out how to do it

Comment: No it cant! You don't seem to be understanding the difference between code which runs on the server and code which runs completely separately on the client browser.

Comment: the variable i am using is razor variable which is accessible over javascript as well as view cshtml provided script is in same page of cshtml i am very much close doing it;   if i can access its(razor variable)  value in javascript there must me some way to set and change its value; you can try it though

Comment: Of course not. Look at the value of the `scr` attribute when you first render the page - its html that has been generated on the server and sent to the view. Changing the value of `something` does not update the html. If you want to do that you would need `$('iframe').attr('src', someValue);`

Comment: nah that didnt worked... mvc seems your fav, there is some way budd and  i will do it;  if its not done till now doesnt mean it cant be done at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123530/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dandy).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: duhh i needed to change razor variable value via JavaScript if you read my question properly may be it will add to you expertise i assume this will be "light bulb" moment for you

Comment: @StephenMuecke: the function which i posted in discussion is achieving the objective of updating value razor variable via javascript as of now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Why not you **update iframe src** attribute instead only action:

Give id="myIframe" or any to iframe and then

```
var newSrc='@Url.Action(something, "Treeview")';
$("#myIframe").attr("src",newSrc);
```